# Install filmic Color Mangement when installed with snap

Tags: permissions, snap, blender

I was trying to get the filmic colour management tool for blender however I installed blender with snap so that I could get 2.8 But now I can't change the folders and add the new folder within the snap directory.
Is there any way in which I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Blender 2.8 you already have filmic as it now comes as standard - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render.

For anyone running Blender < 2.8 for any reason, you can use the OCIO environment variable as per the docs - https://sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender

Extract the Filmic Blender files somewhere and create the environment variable:

```
export OCIO=/path/to/where/the/filmic-blender/config.ocio
```

You should add this to your .profile to make this permanent.